# Динамическое контекстное меню TreeViewItem

Tags: wpf

Имеется стандартный wpf контрол `TreeView`, TreeViewItem'ы получают меню при клике правой кнопкой. Проблема в том, что хэндлер SelectAutoTreeItem вызывается в корневом элементе и распространяется до желаемого.
То есть меню по пути генерируется всем нодам (нужно только конечному, на который был произведен клик). Такой сценарий не очень подходит, так как путь может быть длинным, а бд может располагаться в локальной сети
XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
<EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonUp"
    Handler="SelectAutoTreeItem_Click" />
</Style>
```

Codebehind:

```
private void SelectAutoTreeItem_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (FindTreeItem(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) is TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
    {
        BuildAutomationContextMenu(treeViewItem);
        treeViewItem.Focus();
    }
}
private void BuildAutomationContextMenu(TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
{
    var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

    contextMenu.Items.Add(/*Относительно тяжелая выгрузка из базы данных*/);

    treeViewItem.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
}
```

Update:
Моя ошибка. Действительно там пузырьковое распространение.
Следует добавить `e.Handle=true` и `treeViewItem.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true`

Comment: Странно, насколько понимаю `MouseRightButtonUp` это пузырьковое событие и оно должно подниматься вверх по уровню, а не опускаться вниз. Попробуйте добавить `e.Handled = true;` `if(...){...;e.Handled = true;}` Хотя возможно просто неправильно понял вопрос.

Comment: Немного запутался в поведении. Обновлю вопрос через несколько минут

Comment: @FoggyFinder, полагаю, можно оформить как ответ

Comment: Как раз проблема была найдена сразу - мои ошибочные тесты показали тип стратегии туннель. До кучи на msdn написана стратегия директ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71440/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-denis-mochalov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы остановить дальнейшее распространение пузырькового события нужно установить

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Из-за этого еще нужно явно указать что мы хотим увидеть контекстное меню

```
treeViewItem.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
```